Visual Studio Terminal Error When Connected to Ubuntu 22.04 WSL
I use WSL for development. When I start Visual Studio Code and connect it to an Ubuntu 22.04 WSL instance, I always get this error when launching VS's Terminal:

xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
Usage: login [-p] [name]
login [-p] [-h host] [-f name]
login [-p] -r host

From there, I don't get a command prompt :$.
Interestingly, when I open Windows Terminal, navigate to the required path and launch VS using code . command, I still get the error but at least the command prompt appears.
For the life of me, I have been unable to resolve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

How about you start with the required steps to reproduce this?

Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

what's in your startup files? does this happen if you start without startup files?
